# Plink2 "command not found"

Tags: terminal, plink

I have been using plink 1.9 before and today downloaded the MacOS 64-bit^2 version of plink2. I made sure that I was in the same directory as where I stored plink2.exec but I still could not get plink2 to operate on terminal. When I input `./plink2` on terminal, the output was a bunch of command introduction for plink2, which was expected, but when I input `plink2`, it keeps saying "command not found". What am I doing wrong? I have tried searching unfortunately I have yet to see another person with the same problem.

Comment: That may be caused by `plink2` not being on `$PATH`. If you type `which plink2`, it should show an error, meaning that `plink2` is not installed. Programs that are executed as commands are stored in apposite directories listed in the `$PATH` variable such as `/usr/local/bin`. To execute `plink2` as a command, try to move it in a directory that is on `$PATH`.

Comment: Anyway, the "genetics" tag isn't appropriate for this question. This would classify more as a problem with the console/terminal.

Comment: @NicholasObert Thank you! I already put plink2 in the same directory as the files I wish to operate on, but the "command not found" still persists. However, I found out that when I use `./plink2` instead of `plink2` in a command line, it works as well as intended. About the tag, originally I put "plink" as the tag as "plink2" does not exist, but someone changed it for me. I will change it to "Terminal". :)